# Magento Errors - was running fine a week ago - 2 Traces Below

Tags: database, error

I keep getting this error in magento, its not consistent, though it is definitely happening many times a day.  Does anyone know why this is happening, i will admit i am not good in figuring out these stack traces......  Just trying to get the site running correctly again.  Even if you have an idea of where/what i should look into that would be helpful too...  Thanks in advance.  Trace below

There has been an error processing your request
`SQLSTATE[42000] [1203] User db11833 already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections`

Trace:

```
#0 /nfs/c01/h04/mnt/11833/domains/website.com/html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(96): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()
#1 /nfs/c01/h04/mnt/11833/domains/website.com/html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(320): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#2 /nfs/c01/h04/mnt/11833/domains/website.com/html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(459): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#3 /nfs/c01/h04/mnt/11833/domains/website.com/html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#4 /nfs/c01/h04/mnt/11833/domains/website.com/html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#5 /nfs/c01/h04/mnt/11833/domains/website.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(169): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SET NAMES utf8')
#6 /nfs/c01/h04/mnt/11833/domains/website.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(110): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->_newConnection('pdo_mysql', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#7 /nfs/c01/h04/mnt/11833/domains/website.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getConnection('core_write')
#8 /nfs/c01/h04/mnt/11833/domains/website.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(350): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getConnection('write')
#9 /nfs/c01/h04/mnt/11833/domains/website.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(335): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getWriteAdapter()
#10 /nfs/c01/h04/mnt/11833/domains/website.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(360): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getReadAdapter()
#11 /nfs/c01/h04/mnt/11833/domains/website.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php(134): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->getReadConnection()
#12 /nfs/c01/h04/mnt/11833/domains/website.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1348): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->__construct(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#13 /nfs/c01/h04/mnt/11833/domains/website.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1380): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('core_resource/w...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#14 /nfs/c01/h04/mnt/11833/domains/website.com/html/app/Mage.php(490): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getResourceModelInstance('core/website_co...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#15 /nfs/c01/h04/mnt/11833/domains/website.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(208): Mage::getResourceModel('core/website_co...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#16 /nfs/c01/h04/mnt/11833/domains/website.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(213): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getResourceCollection()
#17 /nfs/c01/h04/mnt/11833/domains/website.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(608): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getCollection()
#18 /nfs/c01/h04/mnt/11833/domains/website.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(466): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initStores()
#19 /nfs/c01/h04/mnt/11833/domains/website.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(349): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initCurrentStore('', 'store')
#20 /nfs/c01/h04/mnt/11833/domains/website.com/html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#21 /nfs/c01/h04/mnt/11833/domains/website.com/html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#22 {main}
```

Just now i recieved a different error while in the admin section:

Cannot send headers; headers already sent in `/nfs/c01/h04/mnt/11833/domains/website.com/html/lib/Varien/Io/File.php, line 1`

Trace:

```
#0 /nfs/c01/h04/mnt/11833/domains/website.com/html/lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php(148): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->canSendHeaders(true)
#1 /nfs/c01/h04/mnt/11833/domains/website.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php(106): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->setRedirect('http://www.ostr...', 302)
#2 /nfs/c01/h04/mnt/11833/domains/website.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(348): Mage_Core_Controller_Response_Http->setRedirect('http://www.ostr...')
#3 /nfs/c01/h04/mnt/11833/domains/website.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php(748): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->_redirect('*/*/edit', Array)
#4 /nfs/c01/h04/mnt/11833/domains/website.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController->saveAction()
#5 /nfs/c01/h04/mnt/11833/domains/website.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('save')
#6 /nfs/c01/h04/mnt/11833/domains/website.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#7 /nfs/c01/h04/mnt/11833/domains/website.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#8 /nfs/c01/h04/mnt/11833/domains/website.com/html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#9 /nfs/c01/h04/mnt/11833/domains/website.com/html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#10 {main}
```

Not Sure what is going on , this site was running flawlessly a week ago.....Please help

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need to increase the max_user_connections in your php.ini file.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find the same question already answered :
 - https://stackoverflow.com/a/13396660/3531064
 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079531/mysqli-error-user-already-has-more-than-max-user-connections-active-connectio
It looks like to be a MySQL configuration issue.

---

Hearders already sent are hard to find. The reason of this error is that the response request and headers are sent before your redirect, in general translated by something written in your page.
To track and fix this error there is some tests you can do :
 - check if your file encoding is correct (without BOM)
 - check if there is no space before the `<?php` tag in one of the trace file
 - check if the page don't print anything before your redirect (maybe a missing debug for example) by adding a `die` line `147` in `lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php` just before the redirect. If there is something print in your page, this is the cause of your error.

Comment: Hi , Thanks for your response, I had already read both those links you provided, though the reason this is coming up seems to be different than those situations.  I am also now getting other errors, which i have added into my original post.  Thanks Todd

Comment: Please see my answer I edited it